# twitter text and image

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

Following this easy code:

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=PUT TEXT HERE &url="+"https://www.google.com";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

Its possible to share also with those text and image? Without using `twitter4j` library.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean to say that you want to share link using intent on twitter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this code does is to query all activities that match with the `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and then it searches for the `“com.twitter.android.PostActivity”` intent.

```
try{
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
intent.setType("text/plain");
final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
final List activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    int len =  activityList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    final ResolveInfo app = activityList.get(i);
    if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
        final ActivityInfo activity=app.activityInfo;
        final ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
        intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        intent.setComponent(name);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
}
 }   catch(final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     Log.i("mufumbo", "no twitter native",e );
      }
```

Comment: Thank you I modified the settype and ading a ExtraStream with image I obtain what I want! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try this it is worked for me. I will use it for share my product details. i will get details of product like name,image,description from the server and display in app and then share it to twitter.

Get image url from server.

```
URL url = ConvertToUrl(imgURL);
        Bitmap imagebitmap = null;
        try {
            imagebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                    .getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Post image and text on twitter.

```
// post on twitter
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(
                    Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Check this out, what do you think?"
                            + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                            + sharedescription);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sharename);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    getImageUri(HomeActivity.this, imagebitmap));
            intent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Convert Uri String to URL

```
private URL ConvertToUrl(String urlStr) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(),
                url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(),
                url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        url = uri.toURL();
        return url;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Convert Bitmap to Uri

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
            inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```